# Proving an orthogonal subspace to v.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let **v** be a vector in R^n. Prove that the set

[image]

is a subspace of R^n (called the *orthognal subspace* to **v**.

Comment: Can you explain what you've tried? Do you know the definition of "subspace," and what are you having trouble checking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x,y \in $ Orthogonal subspace. So we have that $x \cdot w = 0 $ and $y \cdot w = 0 $. Hence for $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$

$$ (\alpha x+ \beta y) \cdot w = \alpha x \cdot w + \beta y \cdot w = 0 + 0 = 0  $$

So, $\alpha x + \beta y $ is in the orthogonal subspace

Answer (score 0):

If $a\cdot v=0$ and $b\cdot v=0$ then $$(c_1a+c_2b)\cdot v=c_1(0)+c_2(0)=0$$ What can you conclude?